# achemso single-column-abstract and Helvetica captions

Tags: formatting, captions, two-column, abstract, achemso

I am currently writing a paper with the achemso style package, as required by the American Chemical Society. I can produce the very nice two-column format by just doing

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=article,layout=twocolumn]{achemso}
```

However this fails to produce two nice features I would desire: a single column abstract and small Helvetica fonts in the captions.
Does anyone know which are the additional options that I need to introduce?
Thanks

Comment: The class file does not support the abstract request: the original 'design brief' from the ACS did not require it, and it would now be troublesome to alter the behaviour. I'm not quite clear what you mean about captions. More importantly, the class is intended to support _submission_. All accepted papers are _retypeset_ by the ACS, so provided the editorial office does not complain I usually advise not worrying overly about appearance.

Comment: With captions I mean Figure captions. The figure number (Figure X) appears in bold types in the most recent JACS papers and in Helvetica in communications.

Comment: The ACS have heavily redesigned their journals, and now use a font with out a convenient free clone. The class uses the `caption` package to do the set up of captions: you can use that to alter things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a one-column abstract the TeX FAQ, [1-column abstract in 2-column document](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-onecolabs) is a good start, though in case of `achemso` some additional tinkering with `\maketitle` is necessary.

To tweak the caption font simply use `\captionsetup{font={sf,small}}` as hinted by Joseph.

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=article,layout=twocolumn]{achemso}

\captionsetup{font={sf,small}}

\newcommand*{\sometext}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
    adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,
    adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu
    libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.}

\let\oldmaketitle\maketitle
\let\maketitle\relax

\author{(Author)}
\title{(Title)}
\email{author@world}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
\oldmaketitle
\begin{abstract}
\sometext
\end{abstract}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
]

\sometext

\begin{figure}
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]